# opening a port on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows-10

*I have googled around a lot. I may not have googled the right keywords, if this question has been answered somewhere else, please link me to the question.*

## The Problem

I have a simple node web server I wrote and I want to be able to access the files from anywhere not in my home.

If I connect to `localhost`, it works fine and gives me the file I want

[image: ?image)]

But if I were to connect to my computer's IP, it does not connect

[image: (image)]

I assume it is something to do with my firewall, but I added a rule to allow connections from port 80.

## The Question

What is causing this, and how do I fix it

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need port forwarding by your router, and to give your PC a static LAN address for that forwarding.  This assumes your ISP does not block incoming port 80

Comment: @DaveS, I forgot to include that, I do have a rule in my router, but that should not apply here, because even just using my private IP, it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

It was nothing to do with port forwarding, everything to do with my node application.

I had it listen on `localhost` only, which blocked the other ips